# Get notification after project deployed on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, restful-url

I have a Java web project(a simple RESTful service)deployed on Tomcat server on AWS beanstalk. I would like to run a few test cases to do the sanity check after the project is up. It seems you could only get an email from SNS but I need an HTTP call to invoke my test instance.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What language and framework are you using to build your application? What command does the server run to start your application? Once you know this, you can setup your application to make an HTTP request when it starts. Regarding best practices, you typically want to test your application using the local test environment and a CI service, and not in a production environment.

Comment: @Richard Thank you so much for your comments. This project is more like a legacy one. I want to make it easier for maintenance but I am afraid adding changes will break it down. The project is manually deployed on AWS beanstalk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the hooks in the dir

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/
```

You can create a new one with the check and upload it there using .ebextensions dir

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Is the hook available only on Custom Platforms? The approach I am taking is trying to add a .ebextensions file to link with SNS.

Comment: i use it with ruby platform, refer to the docs about custom things.